# How do I retrieve an Excel cell value in another cell, as text, formatted as in the origin cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 cells with custom currency formatting.

I would like to display a text next to their sum, which describes the sum being made.

So I would like to write `= "" & textAsDisplayed(A1) & "+" & textAsDisplayed(A2)`

Does such a function exist in the worksheet or do I have to make a VBA function ?

Comment: I would advise you to not get into the habit of explaining formulas visually like this; beyond a simple addition it's quite tedious, and at the simple level, if you have 2 numbers with a larger number next to them, likely with single border above and double border below, it is very clear that its an addition.

Comment: "it's very clear its an addition". I agree, but I am trying to communicate with your average lawyer here.  that means some simple things become complex :))

Comment: in the end I wrote a simple VBA function. which sucks as you get a warning about macro etc..

Answer (score 0):

Try  this: Tested and works fine. It will get the text and format it in Dollar(USA) Currency.

```
="" & TEXT(A1,"[$$-409]#,##0.0") & "+" & TEXT(A2,"[$$-409]#,##0.0")
```

Comment: that would concatenate the values, not the formatted text